# How to validate user using info in headers in spring security

Tags: spring, validation, spring-security

Currently I'm creating the web without login page.

I have another website that will send a header with info:

```
user:John
userCode:1234567
```

So my current website will check the content of the headers and validate the user in authentication manager like this:

First I create the `AuthenticationEntryPoint` so the unauthentication user will go there.In the `AuthenticationEntryPoint` I create a token and redirect the user to main page,so before its goes to the main page,spring will authenticate the user and give a token for a valid user to use the page. The code is like this:

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
         if(authException.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("InsufficientAuthenticationException")) {
            if (request.getHeader("user") != null) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(request.getHeader("user"), request.getHeader("userCode"));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
                response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath());
            }
        }
}
```

In the `AuthenticationManager` the process will go as usual and give token if the user is valid. Is there anything I need to change or another approach that can be used in spring?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure pre-authentication should be handled this way, I mean with custom AuthenticationEntryPoint. See ref doc : [Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/html/preauth.html#http403forbiddenentrypoint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case make me think of the [Siteminder implementation example](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/html/preauth.html#request-header-authentication-siteminder), in the reference documentation.
With Siteminder, a header (SM_USER) is passed with the HTTP request.

This is an example for pre-authentication in Spring Security.

Did you try this configuration ?
They begin by defining a "custom-filter" which is an instance of *[RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/preauth/RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.html)*.

Extract of the documentation :

```
<security:http>
<!-- Additional http configuration omitted -->
<security:custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="siteminderFilter" />
</security:http>

<bean id="siteminderFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter">
<property name="principalRequestHeader" value="SM_USER"/>
<property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="preauthAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
<property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService">
    <bean id="userDetailsServiceWrapper"
        class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
    </bean>
</property>
</bean>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
<security:authentication-provider ref="preauthAuthProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>
```

Comment: Thanks, I already manipulate your answer to suit with my situation.